# Null pointer exception when setting results in a textview

Tags: java, android

The application is crashing when pressing the `Computecost` button

```
package com.example.hw_3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;

public class ShoppingExpensesPage extends Activity  

{
    TextView et;
    Button computecost;
    Button save;
    Button cancel;
    RadioGroup drinks;
    RadioButton drink;
    int tottalcost=0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        et=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv11);
          Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
          String val1 = extra.getString("value");
          et.setText(val1);
          computecost=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn11);
          computecost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
          {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                String val;

                int selectedId = drinks.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                drink = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
                val=(String) drink.getText();
                if(val=="Juice")
                {tottalcost=tottalcost+3;

                }
                else if (val=="Cola")
                {

                    tottalcost=tottalcost+2;

                }

                et.setText(Integer.toString(tottalcost));
            }
          });

          save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn21);
          save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
          {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                 String  str=Integer.toString(tottalcost);//(String) et.getText();
                returnIntent.putExtra("return", str);
                 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
                 finish();                  
            }
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way to compare `Strings`

```
if(val=="Juice")
```

In Java, "==" compares the reference of the `Objects` but not their values. You need to use `.equals()`

```
 if("Juice".equals(val))
 {   // do something  }
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then please post the logcat from the error but this still needs to be changed.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't set the view for `drinks`.

```
int selectedId = drinks.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Find a view for it, before `computecost.setOnClickListener`:

```
drinks = (RadioGroup) findViewById(...);
```